# Using Named Credentials with an endpoint running on my machine

Tags: jwt, mulesoft

I am trying to generate a JSON Web Token(JWT) via named credentials as per user. I want to use this named creds for authentication purpose. **So that using them after salesforce providing JSON web token, in exchange my local auth server will provide a token**.

Below are the settings I have added while creating the named credentials as per user.

> **Label** : TestJWTCredential
>
> **Name** : TestJWTCredential
>
> **URL** : -> external-endpoint <-
>
> **In Authentication Part**
>
> **Certificate** : MulesoftJWT
>
> **Identity Type** : Per User
>
> **Authentication Protocol** : JWT Token Exchange
>
> **Token Endpoint Url** : http://localhost:8091/api/provider/token
>
> **Scope** : refresh_token full
>
> **Issuer** :  -> my-username <-
>
> **Per User Subject** : $userId
>
> **Audience** : http://localhost:8091/api/provider/token
>
> **Token Valid for** : 1 Hours
>
> **JWT Signing Certificate** : MulesoftJWT

**Ref** :- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5#language-combobox

*"http://localhost:8091/api/provider/token"* **This is the url of my authorization server which is a mule application deployed on my local.**

Also while calling this named creds from developer console, it gives this error ***System.CalloutException: Unable to complete the JWT token exchange.***
Below is the APEX code,

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setEndpoint('callout:TestJWTCredential/services/oauth2/userinfo');

req.setMethod('GET');

req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer'+ UserInfo.getSessionId());

Http http = new Http();

System.debug('REQUEST :::: ' + req);

HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);

System.debug('RESPONSE  :::: ' + resp.getBody());
```

Can any body help me how to do it.

Comment: Apex code runs on Salesforce platform, `localhost` will not resolve. You can try tunneling via [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: @identigral
I tried with the other external URL(https://....) of my mule app as well but it didn't work.
I found a article related to it. Could it be the reason why I am not able to use named creds as JWT token exchange.

It always throws this error :
**System.CalloutException: Unable to complete the JWT token exchange.**

Comment: Please review this article once...
I missed adding it in previous comment.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310834/can-we-use-named-credential-with-jwt-auth-to-make-google-cloud-requests