# Named Credentials with JWT Token Exchange: problem with "subject_token"

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials

I was trying to setup a Named Credentials with **JWT Token Exchange** (i.e. not the basic "JWT" option) to use GCP Identity Federation and I got this error when doing an APEX Http callout:

`EXCEPTION_THROWN [13]|System.CalloutException: Unable to complete the JWT token exchange. Error: invalid_request. Error description: subject_token must be nonempty..`

The field "subject_token" is not exposed in the Salesforce GUI to configure.  How can I solve this please ?

**EDIT** I understand that the JWT generation (with self-signed certificate or CA signed certificate) option in Named Credentials can be a solution but I am after a more automated and secure way through "JWT Token Exchange".

**EDIT** Unfortunately, the answer [Generate JWT token for external app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324426/generate-jwt-token-for-external-app) does not answer my question.

Comment: NC won't do what you're after out of the box but it's easy to code it in Apex - see linked Q&A.

Comment: I know that Named Credentials with the simple JWT generation based on provisioned certificates will work (provided that the other side of connection verifies the JWT's signature) but I would like to use "JWT Token Exchange" for the added security & operational benefits.

Comment: @jdupont Neither NC option (bearer or exchange) will work with GCP out of the box. NC won't send `subject_token` and there are [more issues](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310834/named-credential-with-jwt-token-exchange-for-authorizing-calls-to-google-cloud)

Comment: @identigral Thanks for confirming my findings about `subject_token`.