# Authentication for Google DocAi Api in Apex

Tags: apex, rest, authentication, google

We try to integrate the Google Doc Ai https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop to send pdfs and receive parsed texts.
I am struggling with the authentication in Apex for the Api call.
I tried this example https://www.salesforceben.com/google-api-and-service-accounts-get-up-and-running-in-30-minutes/
But the bearer I get has no access_token. The flow where I call my Invocable action returns:

"An Apex error occurred: Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange.JWTBearerTokenExchangeException: No access token in response: {...}".

It contains an id_token, but thats not what I need it seems.
I don't know what I have to change.
May be the Scope SCOPE = 'https://eu-documentai.googleapis.com/auth';  or audience_claim (AUDIENCE_CLAIM = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token') I use are wrong (I don't know where I get the exact information).

Or may be I need a different approach. Does somebody have an advise?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310834/named-credential-with-jwt-token-exchange-for-authorizing-calls-to-google-cloud has the snippet that works.

Comment: ...and when you ask questions here, including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the Scope, it was not cleary stated for the DocAi, but it has to be  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'